# Prove $\text {Dom}(f) \subseteq \text {Im} (g)$ for $g \circ f(x)=x$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Given functions $f$ and $g$ such that $g \circ f(x)=x$ then show that $f$ is an injection and $\text{Im}(f) \subseteq \text{Dom} (g)$ and $\text{Dom}(f) \subseteq \text{Im} (g)$.

---

Clearly $g \circ f(x)=\text{I}_X$ where $\text{I}_X:X \to X$ such that $x \mapsto x$,since identity mapping is a bijection, it follows that it's also an injection and from here we see that $f$ is an injection.

On the other hand, $\text {Im}(f) \subseteq \text {Dom} (g)$ is necessarily and sufficient for $g \circ f$ to be defined.

Finally it's easy to see that the number of injections from $A$ with $\text{Card}(A)=n$ to the set $B$ with $\text{Card}(B)=k$ is given by  $$\binom{k}{n}n!\left[n \le k\right]$$

So it follows that if there is an injection from $A$ to $B$ then $n \le k$.
Applying this to the main problem we see that $\text{Card}(\text{Dom}(f)) \le \text{Card}(\text{Cod}(g))$ ,however this does imply that  $\text {Dom}(f) \subseteq \text {Im} (g)$.

So how can I prove the last one?

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ is in $Dom(f)$ then $g\circ f(x)=x$ so in particular x is the image of $f(x)$ under $g$.

Comment: $g(f(x))=x\Rightarrow x\in Im(g)$

Comment: If I understood correctly, $g(f(x))=x$ for any $x\in Dom(f)$, so for any $x\in Dom(f)$, $x$ is the image of some element $f(x)$ under $g$, so it is in the image of $g$. This is true for any $x\in Dom(f)$ which implies the inclusion.

Comment: I didn’t say that $Im(g)\subset Dom(f)$, neither did you ask for it in your question.

Comment: Why would you assume that $g$ is injective? It doesn't have to be. You can have $f:\Bbb N\to \Bbb R$ given by $f(x)=x$ and $g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb N$ given by $g(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor$. Then $g$ is not injective but $g\circ f=id_{\Bbb N}$.